# access column in csv file using for loop

Tags: python, file, csv

There's nothing quite the same on SO, so hence the question:

I have this file structure: (csv file called test.csv)

```
1.What line is this?    1
2.What line is this?    2
3.What line is this?    3
4.What line is this?    4
5.What line is this?    5
```

I want the program to be able to print the first line (1. What line is this?) and then ask for user input (answer=?) and if the answer is equal to what is in the corresponding column, output "Right".

**The code so far:**

It prints the question and asks for an answer, but does not 
1. output "correct" if it's right
2. Move on to the next question, if right

```
import csv
def main():


    with open('test.csv','r') as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
                  questions=row
                  print(questions)

                  answer=input("answer:")
                  answer_correct=False

                  for row in reader:
                      for field in row:
                                for i in range(len(questions)):
                                          if field==questions[i]:
                                                        currentindex=questions.index(field)
                                                        if row[currentindex+1]==answer:
                                                                answer_correct==True

    if answer_correct == False :
        print("Wrong answer, sorry!")
    else:
      print("****You're right!*****")

main()
```

**For an answer, could you please:**

1. Suggest a fix to the code, pointing out the errors and **explaining** the solution
2. Suggest a more elegant fix /snippet to solve the problem using only csv reader and no other imported tools.

**As mentioned the code needs to:**
-present each question, ask for user input (answer), if right or wrong (print right or wrong) and then move to the next question, until end of file

So far the output:

```
['1.What line is this?', '1']
answer:1
Wrong answer, sorry!
>>>
```

**I've also tried this:**

import csv

```
def main():


    with open('test.csv','r') as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
                  print(row[0])

                  answer=input("answer:")
                  answer_correct=False

                  for row in reader:
                      for field in row:
                                          if answer==row[1]:
                                              answer_correct==True

    if answer_correct == False :
        print("Wrong answer, sorry!")
    else:
      print("****You're right!*****")

main()
```

Comment: Please see update - with a better try from me. Still doesn't work though - but I sense I'm close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote little snippet, which works.

```
import csv
with open('questions.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        question, correct_answer = row
        print(question)

        answer = input()
        if answer == correct_answer:
            print("Wow! Su much knowledge!")
        else:
            print("Still trying")
```

Seems like you has wrong indents in your code.
And block which checking your answer will be executed after the whole cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your CSV file does actually have commas as in:

```
1.What line is this?,1
2.What line is this?,2
3.What line is this?,3
4.What line is this?,4
5.What line is this?,5
```

You could rework it as follows:

```
import csv

def main():
    with open('test.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_input:
        for question, correct_answer in csv.reader(f_input):
            answer = input(question)

            if answer == correct_answer:
                print("**** You're right! ****")
            else:
                print("Wrong answer, sorry!")

        print("All done")

main()
```

For example:

```
1.What line is this?1
**** You're right! ****
2.What line is this?5
Wrong answer, sorry!
3.What line is this?7
Wrong answer, sorry!
4.What line is this?4
**** You're right! ****
5.What line is this?5
**** You're right! ****
All done
```

This uses a single for loop to iterate over your questions. When using a `csv.reader()`, as you have seen, you iterate over the entries one by one. Each time you do this, you advance the location in the file. In your code, you have two such for loops. The effect is that the first one reads one entry, the next for loop then reads more, it does not start from the top again. The problem then is that the first one has now also moved on, i.e. they are not independent. So your main issue is simply having two lots of `for row in reader`.

Note: In Python 3, when using a [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.reader), you should open the file with `newline=''`.